# How to place a ToolbarItem at the trailing edge?

Tags: macos, swiftui, toolbar

I'm trying to place a toolbarItem on the trailing edge of the Toolbar (MacOS).
I've gone thru the documentation, and found the following:

.automatic: item is placed in the **center**

.bottomBar: N/A for MacOS

.cancellationAction: relevant for sheets

.confirmationAction: relevant for sheets

.destructiveAction: relevant for sheets

.keyboard: item placed in the **Touch Bar**

.navigation:  items placed in the **leading edge** of the toolbar ahead of the inline title if that is present in the toolbar.

.navigationBarLeading: N/A

.navigationBarTrailing: N/A

.primaryAction: placed at the **leading edge** of toolbar

.principal: placed in the **center** of the toolbar

.status: placed in the **center** of the toolbar

In essence, none of these places my item in the **trailing edge** of the toolbar.
You guys have any ideas of how to overcome this?

Comment: I also have the same doubt. Using macOS dev app with SwiftUI.

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me using macOS with the right-aligned ToolBar.

I simply used a **Spacer** before defining the ToolBar elements. In the example below with the "plus" button.

[image]

```
.toolbar(content: {
    
    Spacer() // the Spacer pushes to the right side of the toolbar area.

    Button {
        showingSheet = true
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "plus")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet, onDismiss: callbackOption, content: {
        // any code view                
    })            
})
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Spacer should be added inside a ToolbatItem { }

Answer (score 2):

Cannot add comment, this works:

```
ToolbarItem {
    Spacer()
}
```

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2DTo.png)

Comment: To be clear, you add this before the next ToolbarItem that you want right-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution for modern (iOS 14+) SwiftUI:

```swift
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
    Spacer()
    Button("Action") {} 
  }
}
```