# How can I place a ToolbarItem on the right side of the menuBar?

Tags: macos, swiftui

SwiftUI, macOS.

When I try to do this:

```
ToolbarItem (placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            // content
                        }
```

I get a compile error:
'navigationBarTrailing' is unavailable in macOS

So how would I place content on the right side of the menu bar?

Comment: `.automatic` seems to do it for me.

Comment: In my case [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70761082/2624880) worked.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant Toolbar (because macOS app main menu bar, the only, does not allow to put items to the right - you need to operate with `NSStatusItem` for that).

So for toolbar I believe you can use `confirmationAction` placement to forcefully put items in trailing (right-side) location. See below Apple's doc:

```
    /// The item represents a confirmation action for a modal interface.
    ///
    /// ...
    ///
    /// In macOS and in Mac Catalyst apps, the system places
    /// `confirmationAction` items on the trailing edge
    /// in the trailing-most position of the sheet and gain the apps accent
    /// color as a background color.
    ///
    /// ...
    /// 
    public static let confirmationAction: ToolbarItemPlacement
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it work, but then again, not quite. I am also having an item placed in the center (placement: .principal). For some reason, I can't seem to have both. Any ideas?